# Is it possible to extend Intellitrace events?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellitrace

Specifically, what I'd like to do is raise new events from my apps and libraries, similar to those exposed by ADO.NET.

Real life scenario: a patch for NHibernate that shows executed queries even when they are cached (and, therefore, don't reach the ADO.NET layer)

I found a lot of documentation about *using* Intellitrace and intellitrace, but none about *generating* it.

Is this even possible? Or is everything hardcoded in the guts of VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this example](http://blog.qetza.net/en/2010/03/08/vs-2010-personnalisation-des-vnements-de-lintellitrace/) to see how you can define your own IntelliTrace Events.

Comment: Answers consisting only of a link are prone to link rot. You should include the essential parts of the linked post within your answer.