# How to create your own Intellitrace events in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellitrace

It appears this question was last-asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552992/is-it-possible-to-extend-intellitrace-events), for Visual Studio 2010, providing a link to an undocumented and unsupported solution. I assume this situation has been improved.

In Visual Studio 2017, how do you create your own custom Intellitrace Events?

Comment: Like and Subscribe™ if you'd like to see more Questions Without Answers®

Comment: I'd also like to understand a bit more about this and see if there would be a way to share custom intellitrace configuration with other developers, for instance by adding something to the solution or consuming it via NuGet packages. Can't find anything that isn't about modifying files in the Visual Studio installation folder, which really sucks.